# Create array of struct scatterlist from buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build an array of type "struct scatterlist", from a buffer pointed by a virtual kernel address (I know the byte size of the buffer, but it may be large). Ideally I would like to have function like init_sg_array_from_buf:

```
void my_function(void *buffer, int buffer_length)
{
    struct scatterlist *sg;
    int sg_count;

    sg_count = init_sg_array_from_buf(buffer, buffer_length, sg);
}
```

Which function in the scatterlist api, does something similar? Currently the only possibility I see, is to manually determine the amount of pages, spanned by the buffer. Windows has a kernel macro called "ADDRESS_AND_SIZE_TO_SPAN_PAGES", but I didn't even manage to find something like this in the linux kernel.

Comment: You have to know which device you are preparing this scatter-gather list for. Each device may have its own constraints. You have to take them into account. To answer to your question it's crucial to know what are your next steps with this SG list. Show more code.

Comment: I want to use the the scatter-gather list as an input buffer for a virtqueue, i.e. I want to pass it to the virtqueue_add_inbuf function. I also not quite understand why this matters, as a properly formed scatter-gather list, for a given buffer should according to my understanding, describe a chunk of memory, by pointing to the correct pages, offsets and lengths within those pages. And this description is dependent on the definition of struct scatter list and the buffer itself. A properly formed list should be handled correctly by every api, that supports sg lists.

Comment: Briefly looking at the code I can conclude that users just create single entry SG list for that. Check: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/hw_random/virtio-rng.c#L45

Comment: Where did you get this limitation from? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/scatterlist.h#L25

Comment: But my buffer may be, and in fact often is, larger than one page, thus it can't be described by one sg entry. I already had a look, at some more code files, before I posted the question. I managed to find some code that see,s to deal with that problem, however I got stuck, trying to understand what is happening there. Source: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/usb/usbnet.c#L1313

Comment: You don't use real DMA engine backend, there is no alignment and boundary limits. Where did you get all this? I showed you exact constant that defines a maximum length of the entry (hint: `UINT_MAX - (PAGE_SIZE - 1)`. Read code **carefully**.

Comment: Ok I see that macro. But what does that mean in the context of struct scatterlist and a page? As I understand, one entry describes a memory region within a page, that it points to through the page_link field. What does it mean, when offset + length fields are greater that the size of a single page?

Comment: It means that your buffer must be contiguous. This is the only limitation for it. And probably start address aligned to a page size, but I didn't check that.